# Visual Studio 2015 express / SQL Server 2014 Express

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2014-express

Can I use Visual Studio 2015 Express and SQL Server 2014 Express to develop an application for commercial issue?

Can you please show me the licenses?

I know that you can use Visual Studio 2013 Express for a commercial issue but for 2015 I was unable to find the license.

Comment: don't need license if we use `EXPRESS` and `COMMUNITY` edition

Comment: Thanks marc_s for your answer , but for commercial issue I mean. If I would like eventually to sell the app.
Its Visual studio Community for free , what is the difference between it and  Express , thanks in advance

Comment: So you are a Non-Enterprise organization then.

Comment: I believe the new version of "Visual Studio Express" is called "Visual Studio Community".  Answered you below.  The only trouble that you can usually get into is using SQL Server Developer Edition in production.  If you are an individual or if you have a small team (5 or less) you'll be fine to use community/express.

Comment: Thanks Jason Geiger , I m doing an internship in a Company that needs this app , can I develope this application with VS express 2015 and sql server 2014 for internal use or commercial use. I read in VS express License that you are free to use it for what ever do you want therefore for commercial use too.

Comment: @JasonGeiger . My question is not about the software itself but about the application I developed with it. If I develope this application , can the compagny use it without any restriction ?

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio Community Source
https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs

> An unlimited number of users within an organization can use Visual
>   Studio Community for the following scenarios: in a classroom learning
>   environment, for academic research, or for contributing to open source
>   projects.
>
> For all other usage scenarios:  In non-enterprise organizations, up to
>   five users can use Visual Studio Community. In enterprise
>   organizations (meaning those with >250 PCs or >$1 Million US Dollars
>   in annual revenue), no use is permitted beyond the open source,
>   academic research, and classroom learning environment scenarios
>   described above.

From http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=29693
Microsoft® SQL Server® Express License Terms for Redistribution and Hosting

> You may not.. disclose the results of any benchmark tests of the
>   software to any third party without Microsoft’s prior written
>   approval; •   work around any technical limitations in the software;
>   • reverse engineer, decompile or disassemble the software, except and
>   only to the extent that applicable law expressly permits, despite this
>   limitation; • make more copies of the software than specified in this
>   agreement or allowed by applicable law, despite this limitation;
>   • publish the software for others to copy; •  rent, lease or lend the
>   software; or •    use the software for commercial software hosting
>   services.

Comment: Hi @Jason Geiger , I m not Talking abuut the use of VS express 2015 in a Compagny , but the application developed with VS express 2015 by the compagny, is there any restriction in this case ?

Comment: That is a good question but there is no verbiage to be found about that.  It would comparable to Microsoft owning book rights for a book written in Word.  You should be good.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jason Geiger , I was sure that isn't a restriction about it, like you said , like a book written in Word.